# Javascript onclick function stops HTML5 required from working

Tags: javascript, html

Good day,

I am working on a form where all my text fields have a required attribute; I noticed that when i clicked on submit required attribute does not show a pop up to validate if a field is empty.

I have two submit buttons on my page both using an onclick submitform function; One opens up a new tab and the other submits the form and goes to a new page.

For debugging purposes i remove the button that opens up a new tab and remove the onclick attribute on my second button and it work; I have been googling all day but i cannot seem to find the same scenario i have at the moment.

I believe it has to do with my JS but i am not sure what to add or remove on my code; Please see my code below.

JavaScript

```
 function submitForm(action,newtab)
 {
    document.getElementById('add2').target = newtab ? '_blank' : '_self';
    document.getElementById('add2').action = action;
    document.getElementById('add2').submit();
 }
```

HTML

```
 <form id="add2" action="add5.php" method="post">
 <input placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1"
 name="fname" maxlength="128" size="30" required>
 <input placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="12"
 name="lname" maxlength="128" size="30" required>
 <button tabindex="3" value="Save"
 name="save" onclick="submitForm('add3.php',1);" 
 type="submit">Child Information</button>
 <button tabindex="4" value="Save"
 name="save" onclick="submitForm('add5.php',0);" 
 type="submit">Save Details</button>
 </form>
```

I have a button attribute but i have set it to type="submit" and i am pretty much sure that works as i have already tested it when i removed the onclick functions; My question is can i required attribute worked without removing the onclick function of JavaScript?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Editing question as HTML code was not displayed

Comment: Please provide the example code that you think should work but doesn't

Comment: Unless it's a typo here, you're missing a quote: `name="save onclick="`

Comment: had a hard time getting html to display; yes the save where a typo

Comment: hi guys the code pretty much work but when required is added to the text fields it does not work; i discovered that it was an onclick stopping required from working; when i removed the child information table and left the fields blank and click save details required field immediately works; So im trying to figure out why is onclick stopping required from working; Your insights is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, The problem is that i was binding onClick method to the submit. The onClick will trigger first which results in it getting past the validator.

Solution is i change the onClick to onSubmit on my HTML code.

```
<button tabindex="3" value="Save"
name="save" onsubmit="submitForm('add3.php',1);" 
type="submit">Child Information</button>
<button tabindex="4" value="Save"
name="save" onsubmit="submitForm('add5.php',0);" 
type="submit">Save Details</button>
```

Comment: it's better to use `onsubmit` attribute of `form` instead of `onsubmit` attribute of `button`, because in JS you can block submit action by invoking `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use the "checkValidity()" method on the form before submitting in your onclick function like this:

```
if($("#add2").checkValidity()) { 
 document.getElementById('add2').submit();
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36uv2e52/33/

Comment: Kudos! Way better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `required` you can simply check the values before you submit.

```
function submitForm(action,newtab) {
    fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
    if (fname == "" || lname == "") {
        alert("First and last name are required");
        exit;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('add2').target = newtab ? '_blank' : '_self';
        document.getElementById('add2').action = action;
        document.getElementById('add2').submit();
    }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have thought before posting my question as a workaround but i have more than 2 fields on my page i only had 2 on my question as an example cause i find it hard for the readers to read it if i posted all